# Android Linkify TransformFilter is not transforming

Tags: android, transform, hyperlink, linkify

I'm working with a CheckBox that needs to hace some links appearing as text, not urls. I'm using something like this:

```
        TransformFilter transformer = new TransformFilter() {
        @Override
        public String transformUrl(Matcher match, String url) {
            Log.d("                ", match.toString() + " ||||| " + url);

            return url.substring(1, url.length() - 1);
        }
    };

    Linkify.addLinks(acceptCheckbox, Pattern.compile("\\(.*?\\)"), null, null, transformer);
```

If I understand well, if the text in the checkbox contains "(something here)" it should output "something here" without parentheses.

This is just a test before adding the link ie. (go to google-http://www.google.com)

The thing is the links look like links but they are not modified (still with parentheses). Even if I put a schema or I hardcode the String in transformUrl method nothing happens.

I tried with setting autoLink to none, setAutoLinkMask(0), and maybe some more but still stuck. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Oh! I finally found that the TransformFilter is used when you click on the link so you can have "google" and return "http://www.google.com". But I need the opposite, I just want the link to appear like in a web page with <a href... and not showing the entire URL. Someone?

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up using html code in the android:text attribute on the Checkbox.

Just be careful if you are saving the html code in strings.xml, you must escape entities:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Visit Google</a>

&lt;a href=\"http://www.google.com\"&gt;Visit Google&lt;/a&gt;
```

Regards